# Integrate Native sdk in react native using react-native init

Tags: android, react-native

I am setting up a new react native application and new to react-native.
I have a native SDK to integrate which capture an image using the camera and scan the document. NPM wrapper of this SDK not available.

I started my project using react-native init.

I have googled a lot but didn't solve my problem. Please provide some guides which help me to integrate this SDK

Haven't try any particular thing yet, am too confused

I expect just guides which helps me to complete my task, any example will be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

For installing SDK use this

sudo apt update && sudo apt install android-sdk

Comment: My mistake for not clarifying things in question SDK means a library which was initially meant for andriod